# Can't able to add repo (Helm is not accepting Encrypted ( ?path=) REPO URL )

Tags: kubernetes-helm

My private repo consists of ( ?path= ) in it while trying to reach index.yml.

```
$ helm repo add helm https:///HelmChart/?path=/index.yaml
Error: looks like "https:///HelmChart" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch https://*****************/HelmChart/index.yaml : 404 Not Found
```

Help me to add my private repo which consist of ?path= in the URL to helm repo add.